# Using html input tag while iterating over Django fields

Tags: html, django

1. I want to iterate over fields list in Django so as to create a generalized template for major of my forms.
2. The problem I face is that my form is not considered as valid when I'm using the input fields.
3. I want to stick to input fields as I'm using materialize css .

Below is my
form_template.html

```
    <div class="row ">
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {% ifequal field.name "password" %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s3 xl12">
                <input id="{{ field.name }}" type="password" class="{{ 
                field.name }}">
                  <label for="{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endifequal %}
    {% ifnotequal field.name "password" %}
        {% ifequal field.name "email" %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s3 xl12">
                    <input id="{{ field.name }}" type="{{ field.name }}" class="validate">{{ form.field }}
                    <label for="{{ field.name }}" data-error="Not a valid email"
                           data-success="Valid Email">{{ field.label }}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endifequal %}
        <br>
        {% ifnotequal field.name "email" %}
            {% ifequal field.name "album_logo" %}
                <div class="file-field input-field col s3 xl12">
                <div class="btn">
                    <span>File</span>
                    <input type="file" multiple>
                </div>
                <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                    <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload an album cover">
                </div>
            {% endifequal %}
            {% ifnotequal field.name "album_logo" %}
                {% ifequal field.name "date_joined" %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s3 xl12">
                            <input id="{{ field.name }}" type="date" class="datepicker">{{ form.field }}
                            <label for="{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endifequal %}
                {% ifnotequal field.name "date_joined" %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s3 xl12">
                            <input id="{{ field.name }}" type="text">
                            <label for="{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endifnotequal %}
            {% endifnotequal %}
        {% endifnotequal %}
    {% endifnotequal %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

and UserFormView Class in views.py

```
class UserFormView(View):
   form_class = UserForm
   template_name = "music/registration_form.html"

    # Display a blank form for a new user
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

   # Process form Data here
    def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)

        # Cleaned (Normalized or Formatted) Data

        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        # Returns User Objects if credentials are correct
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('music:index')
    else:
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Would really appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: Can you write field.errors for more spesific help? By the way, you can use custom classes for each form field on your form's widget dictionary. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#specifying-widgets-to-use-in-the-form-with-widgets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to style your form I would suggest to use  [Widget Tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks). When you install it correctly you can use it in your template like:

Css:

```
.inputStyle{
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.slide{
...
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method='POST' action="/" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
     {% load widget_tweaks %}
     {% csrf_token %}
     <span class="">Post the Image via Url: {{form.image_url|add_class:"inputStyle" }}</span>
     <span class="" >Please select an option {{ form.Options|add_class:"slide" }}</span>
</form>
```

Another way to style your forms is to install Widgets in the forms.py
You can install things like [Django Select](http://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django_select2.html) and add it into the form like:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    language = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=Select2MultipleWidget(attrs={'data-placeholder': 'Language'}),choices=settings.LANGUAGES)
    class Meta:
      model = Post
      fields=[
        'title',
        'content',
        'image_url',
        'language',
        .....
    ]
```

don't forget to use `{{ form.media.js }}`in the form.

I hope you get that going. The way you do it now is not the best way ;)

p.s. forgot to mention [Django Crispy Form](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). They are fast to install and easy to handle but I would suggest using widget tweaks since you can style everything with CSS. Crispy can be tricky sometimes and you have to read into the docs...